# Consulta de objetos dentro de otros objetos con Detached Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Requiero realizar una consulta en base a filtros. Los filtros son `Nags`, `TipoCristal` y `descripcion`. Mi objeto `CristalLista` contiene las propiedades `TipoCristal` , `Descripcion` y `Cristal`. Dentro de cristal se encuentra el `Nags`.

¿Cómo puedo realizar esta consulta? Pongo un ejemplo de como lo pensé, pero no funciona:

```
DetachedCriteria criteriaTwo = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Cristal.class);
if(cristalForm.getNags() != null && !cristalForm.getNags().isEmpty()){
    criteriaTwo.add(Restrictions.eq("nags", cristalForm.getNags()));
}
DetachedCriteria criteria = this.createDetachedCriteria();
if(cristalForm.getTipoCristal() != null && !cristalForm.getTipoCristal().isEmpty()){
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("tipoCristal", "%" + cristalForm.getTipoCristal() + "%"));
}
if(cristalForm.getDescripcion() != null && !cristalForm.getDescripcion().isEmpty()) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("descripcion", "%" + cristalForm.getDescripcion() + "%"));
}
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("cristal", criteriaTwo));
return (List<CristalLista>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre la respuesta a mi pregunta y si a alguien como yo le sirve perfecto.

```
    DetachedCriteria criteria = this.createDetachedCriteria();
    criteria.createAlias("cristal", "cr");
    if(cristalForm.getNags() != null && !cristalForm.getNags().isEmpty()){
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cr.nags", cristalForm.getNags()));
    }
    if(cristalForm.getTipoCristal() != null && !cristalForm.getTipoCristal().isEmpty()){
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("tipoCristal", "%" + cristalForm.getTipoCristal() + "%"));
    }
    if(cristalForm.getDescripcion() != null && !cristalForm.getDescripcion().isEmpty()) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("descripcion", "%" + cristalForm.getDescripcion() + "%"));
    }
    return (List<CristalLista>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```